# Powershell get number of files and folders in directory

Tags: batch-file, powershell, scripting, cmd

I am going to write a powershell script that gets various statistics on the dir it is in.

If I do

```
get-childitem
```

I get this

```
d----        06/23/2014   2:49 PM            asdf;
-a---        06/23/2014   2:49 PM         23 New Text Document - Copy (2).txt
-a---        06/23/2014   2:49 PM         23 New Text Document - Copy (3).txt
-a---        06/23/2014   2:49 PM         23 New Text Document - Copy (4).txt
-a---        06/23/2014   2:49 PM         23 New Text Document - Copy (5).txt
-a---        06/23/2014   2:49 PM         23 New Text Document - Copy.txt
-a---        06/23/2014   2:49 PM         23 New Text Document.txt
```

And if I do

```
(get-childitem).count
```

I get

```
7
```

I want to be able to count the number of files in the directory as well as the number of folders. Any suggestions would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you want two different things, so you're probably going to need to run two different commands. Count folders:

```
(GCI|?{$_.PSIsContainer}).Count
```

And then count files:

```
(GCI|?{!$_.PSIsContainer}).Count
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using the following command:

```powershell
$headers = @{ $true='Folder'; $false='File' }
Get-ChildItem |
  Group-Object PSIsContainer |
  Select-Object @{ Name="Type"; Expression={ $headers[$_.Name -eq $true] } }, Count
```

Or all in one line:

```powershell
gci | group psiscontainer | select @{n="Type";e={@{$true='Folder';$false='File'}[$_.Name -eq $true]}}, Count
```

Comment: Simplified it a little...`Get-ChildItem | group @{Expression={if($_.PSISContainer){'Folder'} else {'File'}}} -NoElement`